# How does SQL handle where clauses in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, where-clause

This is only a short question to gain more knowledge about how SQL works.

If I have a query with multiple where conditions and for example the second statement is false, will the rest of the statements which come after the second one in the query still be evaluated or does SQL just skip at this point and begin again with the next row?

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
   WHERE NAME = "PETER"
   AND LANGUAGE = "ENGLISH"
   AND COUNTRY = "UK"
   AND ENCRYPTION = "SHA-1";
```

Our database looks like this:

```
| NAME   | LANGUAGE | COUNTRY | ENCRYPTION |
  PETER, ENGLISH, UK, SHA-1
  PETER, FRENCH, SWITZERLAND, SHA-1
  PETER, ENGLISH, USA, SHA-1
```

**Now when it gets to the second entry, would the query stop at the language condition because it is "false", ignore the following conditions and continue with the next entry or will it still check for country and encryption?**

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. But in general, "SQL" does not do short-circuiting of expressions

Comment: MySQL implements shortcircuit evaluation of the conditions in the `WHERE` clauses too but it doesn't necessarily evaluate them in the order you wrote them in the query. For the purpose of your query it shouldn't matter, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQL` is declarative, i.e., your database system can choose to evaluate the `WHERE` clause in any order.

Furthermore, database systems try to use indices. E.g., if you have an index declared on `COUNTRY`, your database system will use this index to only get the tuples WITH `COUNTRY='UK'`, and it will only evaluate the remaining conditions on these tuples. (I'm assuming this is the only index here for simplicity).

This is stronger than short-circuit evaluation, because in short-circuit evaluation, there is still an order of evaluation. In `SQL`, the way you write your statement does not force the database system to evaluate your conditions in a particular order. The database system will leverage this to improve the query response time.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called "short-circuiting".  In fact, most databases do short-circuit when evaluating `where` clauses -- if they are evaluating each clause one comparison at a time.

However, this doesn't make a difference.  SQL is designed for large data.  The overhead in working with data is reading and writing the data from permanent storage.  The additional computational time is often irrelevant by comparison.  Not always -- long strings, JSON fields, complex arithmetic, and the like can add important processing time.

If you care about performance, you should add appropriate indexes.  The best for your query would be on `MY_TABLE(NAME, LANGUAGE, COUNTRY, ENCRYPTION)` (or any index that starts with these four columns in any order).  Proper use of indexes and table partitioning is what you should be learning about if you care about performance.

Comment: How do you know the index (NAME, LANGUAGE, COUNTRY, ENCRYPTION) would be the best one?

Comment: @jarlh . . . I clarified.  Any index that starts with those four columns in any order.

Answer (score 0):

This is called `short circuiting` and SQL Server has it.

In `OR` expression if the first condition is true it does not check other condition like:

for example see this simple query, see `(2 / @a = 1)` should return error
but it is not evaluated

```
DECLARE @a INT = 0
DECLARE @b INT = 10

SELECT 'name' AS Name
WHERE @b = 10 OR (2 / @a = 1)
```

In `AND` expression if the first condition is false it does not check other condition like:

for example see this simple query, see `(2 / @a = 1)` should return error
but it is not evaluated

```
DECLARE @a INT = 0
DECLARE @b INT = 10

SELECT 'name' AS Name
WHERE @b = 14 and (2 / @a = 1)
```

In your question since you are using `AND`, it does not check other conditions if first condition is false

Answer (score 0):

SQL checks every condition in WHERE clause until first failed condition found, then it skips the row. Otherwise row is returned.